# How to get a total value by computing the property of different objects in knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to get the total amount of the meals ordered by all the passengers. I am new to    knockout.js and I do't know how this viewModel is working. can you please clear me where is the class and how to reference the properties of that class.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-        ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/knockout-3.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
        function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
            var self = this;
            self.name = name;

            //meal property is observable . if not then formatted price won't listen to the change of the meal event.
            //Following line indicates that the meal property has been assigned initial meal i.e {mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 20}
            self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);

            self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
                //observable properties are accessed as a function
                var price = self.meal().price;
                return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";
            });




        }

        function GetTotal()
        {
            self.NetAmount = ko.computed(function () {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
                    total = total + seats[i].price;

                }

                return total;
            })
        }

        // Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
        function ReservationsViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
            self.availableMeals = [
            { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 20 },
            { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
            { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
            ];

            // Editable data
            //Seats is an array in which all the new seats are going to be pushed
            //Here if seats is not an observable array then we cannot store any object in it
            //
            self.seats = ko.observableArray([
            new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
            new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
            ]);

            // Operations
            self.addSeat = function () {
                self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
            }




            self.NetTotal = function () {
                self.GetTotal()
            }



        }

        ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
    })
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Passenger name</th>
            <th>Meal</th>
            <th>Surcharge</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
<button data-bind="click: NetTotal">Calculate total</button><span data-bind="text: NetAmount"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.TotalMealsValue = ko.computed(function () {
    var total = 0;

    var seats = self.seats();
    for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
        total += seats[i].meal().price;
    }

    return total;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a4jy96g4/

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of issues. Here is the fixed code:

```js
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;
  self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
  self.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
    var price = self.meal().price;
    return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";
  });
};

function ReservationsViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.availableMeals = [
    { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 20 },
    { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
    { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
  ];
  
  self.seats = ko.observableArray([
    new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
    new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
  ]);
  
  self.addSeat = function () {
    self.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]));
  }
  self.NetAmount = ko.computed(function() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.seats().length; i++) {
      total = total + self.seats()[i].meal().price;
    }
    return total;
  });
};
ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h2>Your seat reservations</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Passenger name</th>
            <th>Meal</th>
            <th>Surcharge</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
            <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
            <td data-bind="text: formattedPrice"></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button data-bind="click: addSeat">Reserve another seat</button>
Total: <span data-bind="text: NetAmount"></span>
```

Your biggest mistake is the NetAmout function/observable. Knockout has the ko.computed() function that updates if any of the variables that he is referencing is an observable. Because the code work with the seats array, if you change any value of it the observable gets updated. You don't need the button.

If you like to update based on the click event, you can try this:

```
self.NetAmount = ko.observable();
self.GetTotal = function()
{
  // here goes the NetAmount calculation. Once calculated, we
  // Set the value in the NetAmount observable.
  self.NetAmount(total);
}
```

Greetings!

Comment: Thanks . I corrected my computed function and its working now.